# Suggest correct TypeScript for React wrapper function which adds 2 functions to wrapped component's props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I developed function wrapping React component for adding undo/redo functionality by keyboard shortcuts Ctrl+Z/Shift+Ctrl+Z. It looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';

interface WithUndoRedoProps {
    addUndoRedo: (field: string, oldValue: string, newValue: string) => void;
    undoRedo: (event: KeyboardEvent) => { field: string, value: string } | null;
}

export default function withUndoRedo<P extends object>(
    WrappedComponent: React.Component<P>
): React.Component<P & WithUndoRedoProps> {
    class WithUndoRedo extends React.Component<P & WithUndoRedoProps> {
        actions: {
            field: string;
            oldValue: string;
            newValue: string;
        }[] = [];
        actionsIndex = 0;
        
        addAction = (field: string, oldValue: string, newValue: string) => {
            if (oldValue === newValue) return;
            this.actions[this.actionsIndex++] = { field, oldValue, newValue };
        }
        
        undoRedo = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
           // Lengthy code to return { field, value } object or null
        }
        
        render() {
            return <WrappedComponent
                addUndoRedo={this.addAction}
                undoRedo={this.undoRedo}
                {...this.props as P}
            />
        }
    };
    
    return WithUndoRedo;
}
```

Later I decided to start using TypeScript for this project. But I don't know how to correctly type this function. It shows TS errors and returns anonymous class.

Also I have a few other questions about typing code. Please suggest where I can find full documentation, good book titles, and any other sources documenting correct typing for React projects.

Answer (score 0):

When I first start writing a lot of higher-order components I had the same confusion that you are having about what type to use for the component.  You will get better with practice.

The issue here is that you need a type that describes *the component itself*, the class or the function.  Right now you've got `React.Component<P>` which describes an *instance* of a component class.

React exports a very helpful type `React.ComponentType<P>` which describes any function or class component with props `P`.  This type is for the component itself, not the instance.

**You need to replace both usages of `React.Component<P>` in your code with `React.ComponentType<P>`.**

---

The other TypeScript issue is hidden by `{...this.props as P}` so you're not going to see it as a red underline. (It will cause red underline problems when you try to *use* this HOC).

**You've got the placement of `& WithUndoRedoProps` backwards.**  Your function takes a `WrappedComponent` which expects to be called with props `addUndoRedo` and `undoRedo`.  It returns a component which no longer requires these props.  So we want to have `WithUndoRedoProps` on the `WrappedComponent` and not on the returned component.

```
export default function withUndoRedo<P extends object>(
    WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P & WithUndoRedoProps>
): React.ComponentType<P> {
    return class WithUndoRedo extends React.Component<P> {
```

You can keep the `as` assertion to avoid having to deal with weird edge cases where `P` refines the types of the `addUndoRedo` and `undoRedo` props.

---

Your `WithUndoRedo` class is storing the `actions` and the `actionsIndex` as properties of the class which is an anti-pattern. It may technically work, but these really should be part of the `WithUndoRedo` component state and modified through `this.setState` only.

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/wEVnkN)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this code but it shows this error:

```
TypeScript error in /.../with-undo-redo.tsx(31,21):
'WrappedComponent' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its element type 'ReactElement<any, any> | Component<P & WithUndoRedoProps, any, any> | null' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'Component<P & WithUndoRedoProps, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Element | ElementClass | null'.
      Type 'Component<P & WithUndoRedoProps, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'ElementClass'.


```

Comment: The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'false | Element | null'.
            Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'false | Element | null'.  TS2786

Comment: Can you post a typescript playground that reproduces that error?  It sounds like another issue of component vs component instance.  Your error message says that WrappedComponent is an instance rather than a component.  That shouldn’t be happening if you are using React.ComponentType like I’ve suggested.

Comment: The second error message is what you get if you have a conditional where you aren’t always returning something from render.  It’s okay to return null but not undefined.

Comment: I really have no idea what is wron with that project. It does not show any errors on "typescript playground" as well if I create new project with `npx create-react-app --template typescript project-name`. But within that project I am trying to convert to typescript it shows this error. I compared tsconfig.json files and they are the same. I also installed all same versions of node_modules, removed node_modules and yarn.lock and reinstalled everything. I continue to see this error. What other configuration files can cause this?

Comment: By removing all other code from project and then adding file by file I discovered that error disappears and appears again if I include this line in any other file (even if the file is not referenced from anywhere): `import Flexbox from 'flexbox-react';`. Very strange issue.

Comment: Also I discovered file node_modules/flexbox-react/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts. There is comment on the first line telling it is `// Type definitions for React 15.7`? Why is it here? And what is the correct way of using flexbox-react if I use react-17.0.1 in this project?

Comment: It looks like the `flexbox-react` package [hasn't been updated in 4 years](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flexbox-react) and [is ignoring pull requests](https://github.com/nachoaIvarez/flexbox-react/pull/46).  I would honestly recommend that you don't use it.  The package itself is [one single file](https://github.com/nachoaIvarez/flexbox-react/pull/46) if you wanted to copy and paste it but it looks like it's mostly just a wrapper around `styled-components`.

Comment: There are currently a lot of code that uses it in the project. As temporary solution, is this possible to instruct typescript (for example, in tsconfig.json) to not use node_modules/flexbox-react/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts?

Answer (score 0):

Error disappears if I replace render() with this:

```
        render() {
            // return <WrappedComponent
            //     {...this.props as P}
            //     addUndoRedo={this.addAction}
            //     undoRedo={this.undoRedo}
            // />;
            return React.createElement(
                WrappedComponent,
                Object.assign(
                    {}, this.props,
                    {
                        addUndoRedo: this.addAction,
                        undoRedo: this.undoRedo,
                    }
                )
            );
        }
```